# Compiling OpenCV 3.1.0 for iOS with a subset of available libraries

Tags: python, c++, ios, opencv

I am trying to compile OpenCV 3.1.0 for iOS, but I only need to use and compile a subset of all the available libraries (imgProc). I tried editing the python build script by adding the following to the `getCMakeArgs` (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/platforms/ios/build_framework.py#L99):

`"-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_core=ON ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_world=ON ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_contrib=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_features2D=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_legacy=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_nonfree=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF ",
           "-D BUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF ",
           "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ",
           "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%s/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-%s_Xcode.cmake " ,
           "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install”`

But it always compiles the whole thing, including all the libraries I don’t need, making the file size of the binary very large (150MB for all supported architectures).

Does anyone have any pointers to what I should be looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this notation
`"-DBUILD_opencv_core=ON ",`
instead of
`"-D BUILD_opencv_core=ON ",`

Answer (score 0):

To update on this question, there is now a parameter `--without <modulename>` available in `build_framework.py` to exclude modules from the build.

The list in the question would then convert to:

```
python OpenCV/platforms/ios/build_framework.py \
--without gpu \
--without calib3d \
--without contrib \
--without features2D \
--without flann \
--without highgui \
--without legacy \
--without ml \
--without nonfree \
--without objdetect \
--without photo \
--without stitching \
--without video \
--without videostab \
output-path
```

Little addition: I stumbled upon `python` in my path being Python 3. That led to "ERROR: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". `which python` helps to clarify that.